# Magento 2 social share facebook messenger button?

Tags: magento, magento2, facebook-messenger, share-button

How can add url link for facebook messenger social share icon on product detail page?

[image]

Check for reference other social icons:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226323/magento-2-social-share-buttons/226332

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in catalog_product_view.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.social">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.socialmedia" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/socialmedia.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

And Create new phtml file at following path:

> app/design/frontend/Custom/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/socialmedia.phtml

Add below code in it.

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<div class="social-media-icons">
    <!-- Facebook -->
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode($_product->getProductUrl());?>&t=<?php echo urlencode($_product->getName())?>" onclick='javascript:window.open(this.href,"","width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");return false' title="Share on facebook">
        <img src=""<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Catalog::images/facebook-share.jpg'); ?>" alt="Facebook" width="12%">
    </a>
</div>
```